# Убрать алерт который вызывается с сайта откуда я встволяю iframe

Tags: iframe, embedded, alert

Я в сайт вставляю iframe с внешних источников. В одном из них, когда заходиш в страницу с iframe ом, вызывается алерт. Можно как то убрать его?

Comment: Ну так возьмите и уберите. Там, где алерт написан.

Comment: Нельзя - безопасность.

Comment: Ввыдается сообщение. "Ваш бразуер устарел обновите его". Это тоже нельзя убрать?